# Error in position of numbers in table of contents page

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: image from table of contents]

*please look in page and try to get solution please*

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[title,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{12pt}
\usepackage[width=16.00cm, height=23.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}    
    \title{{\huge \textbf{Design and Implementation of Hardware Scheduler in 32nm }}}
    \date{\hspace*{30pt}June,2015}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \section*{{\\\\\\\\\huge \textbf{Team Members}}}
    \begin{abstract}
    \end{abstract}
    \newpage
    \section*{{\LARGE Acknowledgment\\}}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \chapter{ {\huge VLSI}}
    \section{ {\LARGE What's VLSI}}
    \section{{\LARGE History of VLSI}}
    \section{{\LARGE integrated circuits}}
    \section{{\LARGE Hardware Description Language}}
     \subsection{{\Large VDL\\}}
     \subsection{{\Large Verilog}\\}
\section{{\LARGE WHAT IS AN ASIC}\\}
\section{{\LARGE OVERVIEW OF ASIC FLOW} \\ }
\chapter{{\huge LLF algorithm }}
\section{{\LARGE Scheduling}}
\section{{\LARGE LLF algorithm\\}}
\end{document}
```

this error i cant solve it please help me 
i don't know why number of this page appear under the name

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a full [Minimum Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/50960), so that we can reproduce your error.

Comment: i dont have any minimum example but this error appear in table of contents and i need help

Comment: @MohamedAlaa And we need help to help you. Unless you have the general solution for the halting problem, we're going to need the input that gives you this output.

Comment: code of book   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B82FWjqYD41Lc3pHMGdMZlBZalk/view?usp=sharing   run it in texstudio and look in result  @SeanAllred    and i wait your answer

Comment: @MohamedAlaa My answer is still "give me a *minimal* working example". That document is well over 2000 lines. You may wish to read an introductory book on LaTeX, too. Take a look at `minted` while you're at it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B82FWjqYD41LSDdYclF4TGIzQUE/view?usp=sharing @SeanAllred i try make it sample as i can please look in it and help me to get error

Comment: Thanks – this is the kind of thing you should've put in your question from the start. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: Why do you have those ``\\`` in your section titles? Those of course propagate into the toc

Comment: (Going back to that "You may wish to read an introductory book on LaTeX, too" bit…)

Comment: thanks @SeanAllred for your efforts with me  and am  really sorry because am not helpful in the beginning

Comment: thanks @daleif you are right because i remove \\ and it repair the toc

Comment: it a solution to remove \\ after name of subsections and sections  thanks all really am thankful